# chrome does not return the right .height()

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, height

Okey dokey, I have a jQuery function that checks the height of 2 divs floating beside and applies a background color to the parent element depending on which is taller, it would work perfectly except Chrome does not return the right height when using the jQuery `.height()` method. I have already applied a reset stylesheet. If you go to this link: http://miami.sightofnick.com/balanced/ , you will see an example of what I am talking about. There is a debug box in the corner; also try using a dew different browsers, it works in everything except chrome. Basically, how do I fix/work-around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with `height()` in chrome.

Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/vHLGg/11/

---

Other things are affecting this behavior. If you have `overflow:hidden`. That could be the problem.

Comment: The problem is a bit more dynamic than just some simple text, there are floating divs and more complicated layouts involved.

Comment: Yes exactly, you need to narrow it down and post a code we can inspect.

Answer (score 4):

use

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // your code
});
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  // your code
});
```

this works correctly both in chrome and ff.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correct, you want both columns to look to be at same height, right? You could then use padding-bottom: 1000px and maring-bottom: -1000px, to make the columns in same size, instead of using javascript.

Example:

```
<div id="container" style="overflow: hidden">
    <div id="left" style="float:left; padding-bottom: 1000px; margin-bottom: -1000px; background-color: red; width: 100px;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
    </div> 

    <div id="right" style="float:left; padding-bottom: 1000px; margin-bottom: -1000px; background-color: blue; width: 100px;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
    </div>
</div>
```